# Serilog WriteTo MsSqlServer - LoggerConfiguration for insert to be done synchronously

Tags: c#, .net, logging, serilog

I recently had an issue with Serilog being used in a web application. The issue was caused by Serilogs default behavior when logging into the database to not insert the log immediately, but inserting it in a sink and waiting for a certain amount of time or a number of logs before inserting them into the database. This, in my mind, is an asynchronous behavior.

What i wanted to do was to configure my logger to insert the logs into the database without waiting (synchronously).

The solution i found was this:

```
var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .WriteTo
            .MSSqlServer(connectionString, 
                        tableName, 
                        columnOptions: columnOptions, 
                        autoCreateSqlTable: true,
                        period: new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0))
            .CreateLogger();
```

which as you can see, means i wait for a period of Timespan(0, 0, 0) which is 0 before "flushing the sink" into the database.

Has anyone found an alternative solution to this?
Is there any reason for which the solution above is not "best practice"?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: This is still asynchronous -- it just buffers and logs "as soon as possible". If your database can't keep up, the logging there will still start lagging behind, your application will not pause and wait for the logging to be written. If you have a hard business requirement that processing not proceed until the request is logged, you probably just want to do an explicit method for that, bypassing Serilog altogether. (Or you can just make your database promise it will always be fast enough, of course.) If you just want best-effort, this will do.

Comment: @JeroenMostert You are perfectly right...as long as there is a new thread it is asynchronous and this is what happens. Thank you for your answer. It's not really a hard business requirement issue but more of a complicated architecture which didn't take into account any race conditions that were generated by using Serilog.

Comment: @Florinache SQL Server's a "sink of last resort" for me: it works but has a lot of drawbacks, not least being that it can interfere with other app functions (and hey, you can't log database connectivity issues! :-)). Have you considered using an alternative data store for the log events?

Comment: @NicholasBlumhardt I agree that logging to SQL offers some/a lot of drawbacks. Unfortunately changing this isn't an option for me at this time but I will consider an alternative data store in the future (i.e.: Table Storage), thank you for this suggestion. However, I am not sure if this will offer me any synchronous options and offer me a true solution to the problem at hand.

Comment: @Florinache I was referring to: _Is there any reason for which the solution above is not "best practice"?_ :-)